# remove lower values in select 1 when selected in select 2 is greater

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Please help me with this code.

I have 2 select boxes. Select box 1 contains the years of "from". While the 2nd Select box contains the years of "to". I want to disable the years of "to" if the selected year of "from" is greater than or equal to it's value. I do some looping in here using [php](/questions/tagged/php). I already tried some related [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) codes but nothing works.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<?php
    $starting_year  = 1950;
    $ending_year    = 2014;
    $to = "";
    $from ="";

    for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
        $years[] = '<option value="'.$from.'">'.$starting_year.'</option>';
    }
?>

<select class="form-control select2me" name="from" id="from">
    <option value="" disabled selected></option>
    <?php echo implode("\n\r", $years);  ?>
</select>

<select class="form-control select2me" name="to" id="to">
    <option value="" disabled selected></option>
    <?php echo implode("\n\r", $years);  ?>
</select>
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? In this code both "from" and "to" look exactly the same. BTW, I'd rather do this with JavaScript, on the client side.

Comment: Yes. The codes of the select boxes are the same. I want to remove the lower values in "to" if I selected one value in "from". That is what I really mean.

Comment: Better to use datepicker

Comment: you can also use, just add `onchange` event to `from` select box like `name="from" id="from" onchange="myfunc()"`, option values are nothing as $from variable is null, which should be `$starting_year`
`function myfunc()
    {
        var e = document.getElementById("from");
        var strUser = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);

        var f = document.getElementById("to");
        var text = '';
        for (var i = strUser + 1; i < strUser + f.options.length; i++)
        {
            text += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+"</option>";
        };
        f.innerHTML = text;
    }`

Comment: Woah! It's working! Thank you so much for a quick response. :D It really do help me a lot. Thank you. :)

Comment: @janie you need to reset your second select box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece if code

```
$('#from').on('change', function() {
    var val = this.value;
    disableSmallerYear(val);
});

var disableSmallerYear = function (val) {
    $('#to option').each(function(){
        if (this.value <= val) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vgjq7qn6/

Comment: But it actually works for me. I just modified the last line to $(this).remove();

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve your problem

**HTML Code**

```
<table>
    <tr >
     <td valign="top">
        <select class="formClass">
            <option value="">select</option>
            <option value="2015-09-01">2015-09-01</option>
            <option value="2015-09-02">2015-09-02</option>
            <option value="2015-09-03">2015-09-03</option>
            <option value="2015-09-04">2015-09-04</option>
            <option value="2015-09-05">2015-09-05</option>
        </select>
    </td>   
    <td valign="top">   
        <select class="toClass">
            <option value="">select</option>
            <option value="2015-09-01">2015-09-01</option>
            <option value="2015-09-02">2015-09-02</option>
            <option value="2015-09-03">2015-09-03</option>
            <option value="2015-09-04">2015-09-04</option>
            <option value="2015-09-05">2015-09-05</option>
        </select>
    </td>   
    </tr>
    </table>
```

**Js code**

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.formClass', function (e) {
        removeSmaller();            
    });

    function removeSmaller()
    {

        //enable all options///
        $('.toClass option').each(function () {
             $(".toClass").val('');
             $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            //$(this).show();
        });

        $('.formClass option:selected').each(function () {
           var select = $(this).parent(),
           optValue = $(this).val();
            //alert(optValue);

           if($(this).val()!=''){
               $('.toClass').not(select).children().filter(function(e){
                   if($(this).val()<=optValue)
                       return e
                }).prop('disabled', true);
               //}).hide();  //If you want to hide then uncommment this and comment upper one
           }
        });
    }
});
```

I have made select value static (In YYYY-MM-DD format ).

Answer (score 0):

On each select you should first reset second select box:

```
$('#from').on('change', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    disableSmallerYear(val);
});

var disableSmallerYear = function (val) {
     $('#to').prop('selectedIndex', 0).find('option').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", this.value <= val);
     });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a **filter** with jQuery?

```
$('option').filter(function() {
    return this.text < desired_value;
}).prop("disabled", true);
```

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/uq9f2f4a/

Comment: I've tried some. But not this like this structure. I will try this, anyway. Thank you. :)

Comment: The 2nd select box is the one should have a disabled option. That is why there are 2 select boxes. :)

Comment: Rememeber that you can choose the select you want to operate with selectors: "select#to > option" and then filter. I actually tried it and it seems to work! Let me know.

Comment: How will I construct this?